# Package missing error while running a Sqoop Java Program through a Swagger Rest API call

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, swagger

I have a java program to import data from a table to hdfs using sqoop options. The code executes fine when executed as stand alone in eclipse. But if i call the same program through a rest api using swagger (Nothing fancy, in the rest code i create an object of first class and call the method) , I get an error that it can not find the hadoop.io package.

> error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
>   import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;

Can some one please help why its working in standalone java program but not when called through swagger ? I have imported  hadoop and sqoop packages via maven.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the package `hadoop-common` : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.0

Comment: I already have hadoop-commons imported. Thats the reason the stand alone program executes .

Comment: You may have the `hadoop-common` imported in your IDE but not in your pom.xml